# What is the maximum of the ratio $\vartheta(G)/\alpha(G)$?

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory

A maximum [independent set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independent_set_%28graph_theory%29) is a largest independent set for a given graph $G$ and its size is denoted $\alpha(G)$. And the [Lovász number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lov%C3%A1sz_number) of $G$ is denoted $\vartheta(G)$. $\vartheta(G)\geq \alpha(G)$ by definition, then the question is what will the 
$$\max\limits_G \frac{\vartheta(G)}{\alpha(G)}$$
be? Any known results about this topic will be welcome! One can give examples to show how big could the ratio $\vartheta(G)/\alpha(G)$ be or counter-examples to show the ratio will go to infinity. Any help or suggestions will be appreciated!

P.S. here is a related question:[Cliques, Paley graphs and quadratic residues](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/48591/cliques-paley-graphs-and-quadratic-residues).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is infinite, in fact much stronger versions are also true, see e.g., Theorem 1 here:
http://arxiv.org/abs/cs/0608021
(Shannon capacity is between $\alpha$ and $\vartheta$.)

Answer (score 3):

I don't have a proof, but numerical evidence seems to indicate the ratio is unbounded. Consider the [Paley graphs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paley_graph) $P(q)$. Then it is [known](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LovaszNumber.html) that $\vartheta(P(q))=\sqrt{q}$. On the other hand, [calculations](http://www.research.ibm.com/people/s/shearer/indpal.html) (more [here](http://ginger.indstate.edu/ge/PALEY/)) appear to show that $\alpha(P(q))$ is roughly $2\log(q)$, and of course $\frac{\sqrt{q}}{2\log(q)}\rightarrow\infty$ as $q\rightarrow\infty.$

**Added later:** I checked a little further and it should be noted that when $q=k^2$, where $k$ is an odd prime power, the independence number is known to be exactly $\sqrt{q}$, so I think the calculations I linked to do not include these cases. On the other hand, if $q$ is not of that form, then an old paper of Stephen D. Cohen ("[Clique numbers of Paley graphs](http://www.ams.org.chain.kent.ac.uk/mathscinet/search/publdoc.html?arg3=&co4=AND&co5=AND&co6=AND&co7=AND&dr=all&pg4=AUCN&pg5=TI&pg6=PC&pg7=ALLF&pg8=ET&r=1&review_format=html&s4=cohen&s5=&s6=&s7=paley%20graph&s8=All&vfpref=html&yearRangeFirst=&yearRangeSecond=&yrop=eq)", Quaestiones mathematicae, 11, no. 2 (1988)) apparently shows that the expected value of $\alpha(P(q))$ is $\log_2(q)+\frac{3}{2}.$ Unfortunately, I don't have access to that paper, so I can't investigate this further. Anyway, sorry for the haphazard answer.

Comment: Thanks! Your answer is very helpful! I also considered Payley graphs, but it is not adequate to say the upper bound is infinity because the numerical result shows the maximum is $5.4$ for $q<9973$. Is there some other pattern of graphs whose $ϑ(G),α(G)$ are all known? Thanks again!

Comment: Yes I meant it just looked like it'll be unbounded from that data. I have no idea if it actually is. I am not up to date on the recent literature so I don't know of any other pattern besides the ones listed in those links, sorry! I am sure there are others on MO much more knowledgeable about this stuff.

Comment: Thanks so much! [Here](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/48591/cliques-paley-graphs-and-quadratic-residues) is a similar question shows $log_2(q)+3/2$ will not be the right size.

Comment: Ah yes. Well, as I said, there are people around here who know much more about this stuff than me! Good luck with your investigations!

Comment: Thanks so much Casteels! You're so kindly focus on this question.