# Why have most maximal cliques of Paley graphs odd size?

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, additive-combinatorics, ramsey-theory

I ask this question mainly by curiosity.
See [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/48591/cliques-paley-graphs-and-quadratic-residues) for definitions and a plot of the clique numbers of the Paley graphs for the primes $p\equiv 1 \pmod 4$ up to $10000$.

> - Is there an explanation why more clique numbers are odd than even?

The graphic below displays the proportion of even clique numbers among the first $n$ such primes, $n\le607$, which seems to stabilize around $20\%$.

> - As $p$ grows, is anything known about the limit of this proportion?

[image]